# Change redirect url based on store id

Tags: magento2, event-observer, multistore, redirect-url

I create an observer for **controller_action_predispatch** in frontend to redirect site to particular store url like this:

```
public function execute(
        \Magento\Framework\Event\Observer $observer
    ) { 
      $url = $this->_objectManager->get('Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface')
            ->getStore('1')
            ->getBaseUrl();
      $this->_responseFactory->create()->setRedirect($url)->sendResponse();
      exit;
}
```

the problem is the page is always loading and never redirect and i need to set the redirect url same with previous url, for example if the previous url is http://base.com/storeA/checkout then it needs to change to http://base.com/storeB/checkout